# Complexity of while loop using series

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

For the following code fragment:

```
i = 1;
s = 1;

while(s <= n) {
    i++;
    s = s+i;
    printf("x");
}
```

How can we go about proving the time complexity of this code is $\Theta(\sqrt{n}))$?

Usually, I use sigma series analysis to figure the time complexity but I am having trouble turning this code into series notation and then using the series to find out the time complexity.

Comment: @OmG Please avoid using complexity theory tags for algorithm analysis. The correct tag to use is [tag:runtime-analysis].

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you see, in each iteration `i` is increased by `1`. Hence, value of `s` would be $1 + 2 = 3, 1 + 2 + 3 = 6, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10, \ldots,  \sum_{i=1}^{k}= n$

Hence, $k$ is the time complexity of this code. As we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} = \Theta(k^2)$, and $\Theta(k^2) = n$, we can conclude that $k = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, however would you know I could figure that out using series notation? and proving it mathematically

Comment: @dydxx it's updated.